# Construct associative array with all attachments from each post wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have some special `post`, from `category` "*gallery*" and I want recover all the `attached media images` in theirs. I loop across the `posts` and then I get all media, and save it in `associative array`, but this the result:

**Code (Relevant only)**

```
<?php $args=array(
    'category_name' => $gallery_category_slug,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby'=> 'ID',
    'order' => 'asc',
);
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) { ?>
<?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?> *ID of each post (OK)
<?php the_title(); ?> *Title of each post (Ok)
<?php 
    //Get Attached images from category (post)
    $args_att = array(
     'post_type' => 'attachment',
     'numberposts' => -1,
     'post_mime_type' => 'image',
     'post_status' => null,
     'post_parent' => get_the_ID() //Same ID always
    );
    $attachments = get_posts( $args_att );
    if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
            $aux = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment->ID , 'full' );
            if($aux){
                $post_images[get_the_ID()][]= $aux[0];
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

**Result**:

```
    Array ( [186] => Array ( [0] => http://testdomain/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/WINE.jpg [1] => http://testdomain/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/MASTERBEDROOM.jpg [2] => http://testdomain/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/POOL.jpg [3] => http://testdomain/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/TENNIS.png [4] => http://testdomain/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/ENTERTAINMENT.jpg [5] => http://testdomain/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/EXCERCISE.jpg [6] => http://testdomain/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/BEDROOMS.png [7] => http://testdomain/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/DSC_5854.jpg [8] => http://testdomain/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/DSC_5800.jpg ) )
```

**Desired Result:**

```
Array ( [186] => Array ( [0] => http://testdomain/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/WINE.jpg [1] => http://testdomain/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/MASTERBEDROOM.jpg [2] => http://testdomain/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/POOL.jpg ), [187] => Array ( [0] => http://testdomain/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/WINE.jpg [1] => http://testdomain/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/MASTERBEDROOM.jpg ), [188] => Array ( [0] => http://testdomain/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/WINE.jpg ))
```

I thinkt that I made a mess with the array.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my theory: I'm thinking the issue is with the `get_the_ID()` in `$post_images[get_the_ID()][]= $aux[0];` because `get_posts` changes the global `$post` object that `get_the_ID()` uses. So, I'd place the post's ID into a variable and then use that in the rest of the function.

Hope this helps.

```
<?php
$args=array(
    'category_name' => $gallery_category_slug,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby'=> 'ID',
    'order' => 'asc',
);
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
    $original_post_ID =  get_the_ID();
       the_title(); 

    //Get Attached images from category (post)
    $args_att = array(
     'post_type' => 'attachment',
     'numberposts' => -1,
     'post_mime_type' => 'image',
     'post_status' => null,
     'post_parent' => $original_post_ID //our new variable
    );
    $attachments = get_posts( $args_att );
    if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
            $aux = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment->ID , 'full' );
            if($aux){
                $post_images[$original_post_ID][]= $aux[0];
            }
        }
    }
    endwhile;
?>
```